# Math formulas in Lyx do not display nicely

Tags: lyx

I have a problem in Lyx. When I write a math formula, it is designed only partially and stays in the code level. how do I fix this bug?
As an example, here is a screenshot of a diagram:
[image]

The correct display should be

[image]

Comment: Does it help if you select the relevant text and go to Insert > Preview Box? Also, turn preview to "on" preview in Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Display. If that doesn't work, after turning preview on, restart LyX. Does it work then?

Comment: I just turned on the preview and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Turn preview to "on" in Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Display.